# Does the Magnetic Field do work in Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, work, density-operator

Let's say I have an electron in an infinite potential well. The Hamiltonian is given by:

$$ \hat H | E_n \rangle= \frac{\hat p^2}{2m}| E_n \rangle $$

with $p$ being the momentum and $m$ being the mass. Now, suddenly turn on an electromagnetic field with gauge $(\phi, \vec A)$. Then the Pauli equation holds:

$$ \hat H' |E_m' \rangle = \Big (\frac{1}{2m} (\hat p - q \vec A)^2 - q \hbar \hat \sigma \cdot \vec B + q \phi \Big) |E_m' \rangle$$

Expanding this:

$$ \hat H'|E_m' \rangle  = \Big ( \frac{1}{2m} \hat p^2 + q^2 \vec A^2 +  q\hat p \cdot \vec A + q \vec A  \cdot \hat p- q \hbar \hat \sigma \cdot \vec B + q \phi \Big) |E_m' \rangle $$

We define the interaction hamiltonian as:

$$ H_{\text{int}} = q^2 \vec A^2 +  q\hat p \cdot \vec A + q \vec A  \cdot \hat p- q \hbar \hat \sigma \cdot \vec B + q \phi$$

Let the state be in the initial eigenenergy state: $|E_n \rangle$. After the electromagnetic field is turned on:

$$ H \to H + H_{\text{int}}$$

Before the potential is turned on:

$$ \rho = |E_n \rangle \langle E_n | $$

We use the sudden/adiabatic approximation to get the following density matrix:

$$ \rho ' =\sum_m  | E'_m \rangle \langle E'_m| |\langle E_n | E'_m \rangle |^2 $$

Hence, the work done on the system is given by:

$$ \Delta W = \text{Tr} (H \rho - H' \rho' )$$

Now, let's say I only turn on the $B$ field. Then I have:

$$  \nabla \phi = - \frac{\partial \vec A}{ \partial t} $$

### Question

In classical mechanics we know the $B$ field does not do any work. But over here that does not seem obvious since the above calculations are suggestive there will be work done (?)

Comment: Maybe this other question (and specially the comments) can help you: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28946/work-done-on-charged-particle-by-magnetic-field-in-quantum-mechanics?rq=1

Comment: @RMPsp Hmm .. Why is the classical picture different when I suddenly turn on the magnetic field? (Over there the electron would only go in loops)

Comment: what do you mean by different in the classical case respect to the quantum case?

Comment: @RMPsp Well if I turn on the magnetic field really quickly then an electron which is moving along a straight line it will only start going round in circles. The energy of the particle will be conserved. In contrast the quantum case the average energy will change.

Comment: Actually I realised it will also radiate (in the classical case) :P ...

Comment: see for example https://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~bds10/aqp/handout_charged.pdf, where at the end they solve the quantum case of a particle with external magnetic field. They do not solve the gauge where A=(-y,x,0)B/2, but I guess that if you do it, you can recover the circular motion of the observables <x> and <y>.