# Quantum angular momentum of a particle in an homogeneous magnetic field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, angular-momentum, momentum, commutator

In non-relativistic quantum mechanics, the *canonical momentum* of a particle is defined as
$$\tag{1}
p_i = - i \hbar \: \partial_i.
$$
When there's an external magnetic field (suppose for simplicity that it's constant and homogeneous), the *observable momentum* (or *dynamical momentum*) isn't $p_i$, but
$$\tag{2}
\pi_i = p_i - q A_i,
$$
where $A_i$ is the *gauge dependent* potential-vector associated to the external magnetic field.  While $[ p_i, p_j] = 0$, it's easy to get the following commutator:
$$\tag{3}
[ \pi_i, \pi_j] = i \hbar \, \varepsilon_{ijk} \, q B_k.
$$
So, in the presence of a magnetic field, the **observable** orbital angular momentum isn't anymore
$$\tag{4}
L_i = \varepsilon_{ijk} \, x_j p_k,
$$
and should be replaced by
$$\tag{5}
M_i = \varepsilon_{ijk} \, x_j \, \pi_k.
$$
The commutator of this thing isn't simple.  Unless I made a mistake, I get this:
$$\tag{6}
[ M_i, M_j] = i \hbar \, \varepsilon_{ijk} \, M_k + i \hbar \, \varepsilon_{ijk} \, x_k \, (q \,  \vec{\mathrm{r}} \cdot \vec{\mathrm{B}}).
$$
The last term is weird to my eyes!

Also, for a simple charged particle in the homogeneous magnetic field $\vec{\mathrm{B}} = B \, \hat{\mathrm{z}}$, the component $M_z$ doesn't commute with the Hamiltonian, while $L_z$ do commute:
$$\tag{7}
[L_z, H] = 0, \qquad [M_z, H] \ne 0.
$$
How should I interpret this?  I guess this should be right, since the system isn't closed (there's an external magnetic field!), but I feel a bit hesitant with having $[ M_z, H ] \ne 0$.  For the simple particle in a constant magnetic field (I'm using the symmetric gauge $\vec{\mathrm{A}} = \tfrac{1}{2} \, B \, (- y \, \hat{\mathrm{x}} + x \, \hat{\mathrm{y}})$), I get
$$\tag{8}
M_z = L_z - \frac{1}{2} \, q B \, (x^2 + y^2).
$$
So, for the Hamiltonian
\begin{align}
H &= \frac{(\vec{\mathrm{p}} - q \vec{\mathrm{A}})^2}{2 m} \\[2ex]
&= \frac{p_x^2}{2 m} + \frac{p_y^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2} \, m \omega^2 (x^2 + y^2) + i \hbar \omega \Bigl( x \, \frac{\partial}{\partial y} - y \, \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \Bigr), \tag{9}
\end{align}
I get this commutator:
$$\tag{10}
[M_z, H]= - i \hbar \, \frac{q B}{2m} (\vec{\mathrm{r}} \cdot \vec{\mathrm{p}} + \vec{\mathrm{p}} \cdot \vec{\mathrm{r}}) \equiv  i \hbar \omega \, (\vec{\mathrm{r}} \cdot \vec{\mathrm{\pi}} + \vec{\mathrm{\pi}} \cdot \vec{\mathrm{r}}).
$$
This thing is weird!  I feel uneasy with the usual angular momentun (4) not observable anymore, since it is implicitly gauge-dependent, while (5) is gauge-independent.

So I'm looking for an interpretation of the extra-term in (6) and the non-commutativity (10) (the physical angular momentum isn't conserved?).  How should I consider these commutators?  I have the impression that they may be related to the arbitrary choice of axes origin, while the particle may evolve around any point in the $(x, y)$ plane.

Comment: This seems to be a [check-my-work question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) - do you have any questions other than "is this correct?"?

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28946/work-done-on-charged-particle-by-magnetic-field-in-quantum-mechanics).

Comment: @ACuriousMind, I'm looking more for an interpretation than for a check.

Comment: Are you unhappy with the interpretation of Landau & Lifshitz, v3, Quantum mechanics, XV, pp421ff ? You are rewriting that section in eccentric language.

Comment: @CosmasZachos, how eccentric is my question?  It's standard QM!

Comment: I am only talking about the language. L&L use $\hat {\mathbf v}$ for your $\hat {\mathbf \pi}/m$... Of course it's standard QM... Magnetic fields preserve the magnitude of the velocity.

Comment: @CosmasZachos, I'm not talking about the velocity (I know its magnitude is conserved).  I'm interested in the "physical" angular momentum (which I call $M_i$ to prevent confusion with the usual $L_i$, which is non-observable in this case).  I didn't saw this discussed in any QM textbook.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here I try to give some results that do not rely on the B field being uniform, or a particular choice of gauge. Starting from the definitions of the quantum operators
$$
\vec{M} = \vec{r} \times \vec{\pi} \\
H = \frac{1}{2m} \vec{\pi}^2
$$

Work in the Heisenberg picture, the torque equation is
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\vec{M} = \vec{r} \times \frac{d}{dt}\vec{\pi}
$$

Using Heisenberg's equation of motion,
$$
[\vec{M}, H] = \vec{r} \times [\vec{\pi}, H]
$$

You were asking why the commutator $[\vec{M}, H]$ is non-zero. In general, it is not, as $[\vec{\pi}, H]$ is non-zero. Below are some equations which might be helpful for your analysis.
$$
\frac{1}{i\hbar} [\vec{r}, H] = \frac{1}{m} \vec{\pi} \\
\frac{1}{i\hbar} [\vec{\pi}, H] = \frac{q}{2m} (\vec{\pi}\times\vec{B} - \vec{B}\times\vec{\pi})
$$

Comment: This answer is useful, but it doesn't give the physical interpretation.  The point is that the field being homogeneous, any reference location could be used to define the angular momentum.  But then, selecting a reference location to define $\vec{\mathrm{r}}$ breaks the homogeneity symmetry.  Since the quantum particle doesn't have a definite trajectory and could be anywhere, it becomes obvious why the physical observable $M_z$ isn't conserved.  It is a bit ironic that the non-observable $L_z$ is conserved, while the observable $M_z$ isn't!

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it!  The commutator (10) is the quantum version of the classical time derivative of the angular momentum (classical expressions below):
$$\tag{A}
\vec{\mathrm{M}} = \vec{\mathrm{r}} \times m \vec{\mathrm{v}}.
$$
So, using the magnetic force $\vec{\mathrm{F}} = q \, \vec{\mathrm{v}} \times \vec{\mathrm{B}}$:
$$
\frac{d \vec{\mathrm{M}}}{d t} = \vec{\mathrm{r}} \times q (\vec{\mathrm{v}} \times \vec{\mathrm{B}}) = q (\vec{\mathrm{r}} \cdot \vec{\mathrm{B}}) \vec{\mathrm{v}} - q (\vec{\mathrm{r}} \cdot \vec{\mathrm{v}}) \vec{\mathrm{B}}.
$$
With a magnetic field oriented along the $z$ direction and considering the classical circular motion in the $(x, y)$ plane around any point (not necessarily the origin), we get $\vec{\mathrm{r}} \cdot \vec{\mathrm{B}} = 0$ and
$$\tag{B}
\frac{d M_z}{d t} = - \frac{q B}{m} (\vec{\mathrm{r}} \cdot \vec{\mathrm{v}}) = 2 \omega \, (\vec{\mathrm{r}} \cdot m \vec{\mathrm{v}}),
$$
where $\omega = - q B / 2 m$.  This is the classical version of (10), since $m \, \vec{\mathrm{v}} \equiv \vec{\pi}$ (which is the same as $\vec{\mathrm{p}} - q \vec{\mathrm{A}}$).  If the axes origin is selected at the center of the circular motion, then $\vec{\mathrm{r}} \cdot m \vec{\mathrm{v}} = 0$ and the angular momentum $M_z$ is trivialy conserved.  But in QM, we can't cancel (10) because the particle has a probability to be anywhere in the plane and it isn't just moving in a circle around the origin.

About (6), well, I'm not sure yet, but classically we could let $\vec{\mathrm{r}} \cdot \vec{\mathrm{B}} = 0$.